# Nginx try_files index.php fails to get processed

Tags: wordpress, nginx, config

I have this config setup:

```
location / {
            #try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;  <-- works as expected
#try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args /maintanence.html; <-- does not work
            #try_files $uri /maintanence.html;  < -- switches to maintenance page as expected
try_files $uri /index.php /maintanence.html; <-- also does not work

}


location ~ \.php$ {
    
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        
}
```

1st and 3rd lines work 2nd and last lines do not.

I have noticed that whenever you put any other filename after index.php it just returns raw index.php contents in response.

Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: Because `/index.php` must be in the last position (called **uri** in [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)). If you want a rule that is dependent on the existence of `maintenance.html`, try: `try_files $uri /maintanence.html /index.php;`

Comment: @RichardSmith that defeats the point of the line. The whole point is to re-route to maintenance page if index.php is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment states that you wish to deliver `maintenance.html` if the file `index.php` does not exist.

The `try_files` statement that checks for the existence of `index,php` must be in the same `location` that processes the request.

You could do it in the `location ~ \.php$` block if you want the non-existence of **any** `.php` file to trigger `maintenance.html`, but the solution below will limit the check to `index.php` only.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
location = /index.php {
    try_files $uri /maintanence.html;

    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;            
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;            
}
```

Comment: _The try_files statement that checks for the existence of index,php must be in the same location that processes the request._

Then why does this work? 
**try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;**

Comment: `/index.php$is_args$args` is not a *file* parameter, it is a *uri* parameter. It generates an internal redirection which restarts the search for a matching `location` block to process the rewritten request. The *file* parameters check for the existence of a file, change the URI if necessary, and process the request in the current `location` block.

Comment: I see the last parameter is a redirect all params before that are files. it makes sense now. Thanks!